# Relationship in Excel power pivot not working

Tags: excel, pivot

Im trying to implement the use of Excel pivot table and pivot charts in the company I work in.

I have a few tables containing both date and country, and I used concatenate() to make a unique key in every table and make a relationsship between tables that way (suggested by the IT department with no Excel pivot experience).

I cannot get it to work in any way. Can somebody tell what im doing wrong? 
I attached a picture of the way I connected the tables and a sample of my data below.

I dont have an IT background, so please try to explain as simple as possible.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What **exactly** is the problem? This isn't really an appropriate place to attempt to explain how Power Pivot works.

Comment: It might not be they right place, but i asked the question anyway, since I've no I couldn't get help any other places. 
The problem is, that this method of connection does not work when I create a pivot table - and i'm looking for advice on any other way to build relationsship between my tables so I can access all data when using a pivot table. Right now, it just say: "It might be neccesary with relations between tables".